# How to create link from a CSS dropdown meny to an iframe on slide 2

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, slider, css

Hi I am trying to have a link from one of the subs in a CSS dropdown menu to take me to an iframe on slide 2 in a jquery slider.

Here is a link to the site:
www.thorendahl.no

So what I want is when you click on for example "historie" under "om thorendahl" it will do the same as when you click on "om thorendahl" (jump to slide 2, but open a different html page inside the iframe that show up)

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Change the ID `#slide-jump2` to a `class`, that way it's re-usable.

And then update your `jQuery` to point to the `class` rather than the `ID`

```
$(".slide-jump2").click(function(){
    $('#slider1').anythingSlider(2);
});
```